# How to HTTP request a file using regular expressions

Tags: regex, angular, http

I need to make a request for a CSS file.

I know which folder on the server my file will be in.

What I *don't* know is the exact file name. It will be titled of the form `theme.bundle.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css` where `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is a series of random characters and numbers generated at build time.

My question is, **is it possible to make an HTTP request with a regex to get the name of the matching file(s)**? I don't need help constructing the regex itself, but rather how to utilize one in combination with an HTTP request.

I can't find any information related to the usage of regular expressions to construct an HTTP request, or if this is even possible.

Comment: I doubt this is available in any standard framework. You'll need to write a server script that does it.

Comment: The better question is: Why is this necessary? I assume that you use either webpack or angular cli to build your project. The correct way of doing this would be to use the generated source html file, which will already have the reference to the bundled script. The problem you are having is most likely a xy problem, caused by an error in how you build the project.

Comment: @baao Not the case - there is a valid reason I need to do things this way. I can’t give you a satisfactory explanation why in this amount of space, and it’s not relevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Not possible, unless you have access to customize your server. You tagged this question as an "angular" question. From an Angular standpoint - Angular can't make this happen.

Longer answer: Totally possible! But this ends up being more of a backend question, not an Angular question. You didn't specify which backend you have, so I'll use a Node/Express server as an example. Part of building a server is setting up routing and API endpoints. Consider this code that responds with a particular file whenever the server receives a GET request to /images/background

```
app.get('/images/background', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile('public/img/background.png')
})
```

For your situation, you would need to set up an endpoint with similar logic to this:

```
app.get('/getMyCssFile', function(req, res) {

  // Use NodeJS fs module to loop over files in /testfolder and read the file names
  let matchingFile;
  fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
    // Perform REGEX matching here, if filename matches, then save this file name
    if (matches) {
      matchingFile = file;
    }
  })

  if (matchingFile) {
    res.sendFile(file)
  } else {
    // handle sending error - no matching file found
  }

})
```

On your Angular frontend, you'd just need to request /getMyCssFile, and your server will respond with the matching file.

Comment: I feared this was the case. Thanks for the detailed answer